# WSUS server not working

Tags: http, iis, wsus, client-server

I have troubles getting my WSUS server to work. When clients try to search for updates, they get this error: 8024402C Unknown error.

When I try to reach the WSUS website, I get access denied. I get the following when trying to reach the website from the WSUS server:

[image]

Comment: That screen is from IIS that shows that the incorrect permission for browsing a folder is set.  What server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If the machine is a dedicated **WSUS** server, `uninstall the Directory Browsing module`, and this message will clear.

If the machine has some other app/service/website installed that requires the Directory Browsing module, then this message is unavoidable, and meaningless.

Ref: [WSUS CLIENT COMMUNICATION TO SERVER 2012](http://thwack.solarwinds.com/thread/57078), 
[Ref 2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e3badef-0ff8-40db-a7ab-62a2eecabe92/how-to-configure-selfupdate?forum=winserverwsus)